# Jquery Datatables table. Data out of table border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am using Datatables to manage my Tables, including a method that uses AJAX to edit the table without the need to refresh the page.

It all went fine until I hit a problem, I had to use a larger row with more data in one of my pages and once I click my edit button the data goes out of the table to the right.

Table without any action:
[image]

Table after I click the edit button:
[image]

Table after I click the save button after the edit button (End result):
[image]

My jQuery code (commented it a bit for you guys):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#tableSmooth').dataTable({
    //"bFilter": false,
     "bJQueryUI": true, //Enable smooth theme
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" //Enable smooth theme
    });
    var nEditing = null;
     
    $('#tableSmooth a.edit').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         
        // Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
         
        if ( nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow ) {
            // A different row is being edited - the edit should be cancelled and this row edited 
            restoreRow( oTable, nEditing );
            editRow( oTable, nRow );
            nEditing = nRow;
        }
        else if ( nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == '<img src="../../pictures/save.png" alt="edit" width="20" height="20">' ) { //Has to match line in edit row function
            // This row is being edited and should be saved 
            saveRow( oTable, nEditing );
            nEditing = null;
        }
        else {
            // No row currently being edited 
            editRow( oTable, nRow );
            nEditing = nRow;
        }
    } );
} );


function editRow ( oTable, nRow ) //Edit row 
{
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
    var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
    
//Editing the rows to textboxes/dropdowns for further use

    jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[0]+'" disabled>';
    jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[1]+'">';
    jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[2]+'" disabled>';
    jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[3]+'">';
    jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[4]+'">';
    jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[5]+'">';
    jqTds[6].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href=""><center><img src="../../pictures/save.png" alt="edit" width="20" height="20"></a>'; //Note: Inner HTML has to match code in document.ready above

}


function saveRow ( oTable, nRow ) //Save row using AJAX 
{

       var jqInputs = $('input', nRow); //Only gets <input> values
       var jqSelect = $('select', nRow); //Only gets <select> values

    oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false );//Update table with value for instant display (Not passed trough AJAX rather use JS to prevent possible AJAX error output in table)
    oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false );
    oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false );
    oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false );
        oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[4].value, nRow, 4, false );
            oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[5].value, nRow, 5, false );
    oTable.fnUpdate( '<a class="edit" href=""><center><img src="../../pictures/edit.png" alt="edit" width="20" height="20"></a>', nRow, 6, false );
    oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

The table code is normal table code, nothing special just with `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

I was thinking maybe reload the table after a edit? This would fix the format but `oTable.fnDraw()` is redrawing it but it doesn't fix it. Maybe some other way?

Comment: i pressume not html except table tags, right?
plus, have you noticed the unClosed <center> tag, right?

Comment: @Ori Gavriel Refael Yes only html table tags.. do you know the solution? And yes I notice it.

Comment: have no idea whats wrong in the images, have you double checked the data  columns match the columns number, that your aren't trying to insert 7 fields to 6 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using size="" tags in the textbox to lower the size of the textbox making it not go out of the border. Cheap fix but it works.